# How to implement authentication in postgresql based on Django?

Tags: django, postgresql, authentication

Сould you explain or explain ?
How to properly implement authorization to the django database (without migrations). That is, there is a database, it has a table in which the login and password are stored. We can simply go through authorization when accessing it.

How to make it so that when a user registers, the login and password are entered directly into this table (where the login and password are stored)? An account is also created so that you can log into the database itself under this account.
Initially, we have a server account connected, and when someone does something, we will see that it is the server account that does it, not the user